# Стили для дочерних элементов

Tags: css

Допустим у нас есть два div-а

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Как правильно указать стили дляя div-а two?
Я видел несколько способов и до сих пор не знаю, какой из них правильный

```
.one.two{}
.one .two{}
.one > .two{}
```

Comment: я бы ответил но  вы не принимаете своих ответов .

Comment: Все кроме первого

Comment: Верны и правильны записи: `.two` , `.one .two` , `.one > .two` , разница только в весе селекторов. Статья - http://css.yoksel.ru/specifity/

Answer (score 0):

в такой ситуации лучше всего указать на прямую стиль `.two{}`
или на крайний случай `.one .two{}` или `.one > .two{}`.

Это не верно `.one.two{}` - это подходит для ситуации `<div class="one two"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

1. .one.two{} - в этом случае запись должна быть такого типа `<div
   class="one two"></div>`, если будет вложенность, то стили не
   отработают.
2. .one .two{} - выбирает **все** `<div class="two"></div>`,
   которые находятся внутри `<div class="one"></div>` работает любая вложенн
3. .one > .two{} - выбирает все `<div class="two"></div>`, которые являются потомками `<div class="one"></div>`